# Can't access the response variable from chrome.runtime.sendMessage. (Closure?)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, scope

I feel stupid because I've been trying to access this response variable for a while and I guess I do not understand closures or scope well enough, so please help.

I'm working on a chrome extension and I am sending a message from contentscript.js to background.js and receiving the response. Now I want to return the response and be able to use it in contentscript.js. Seems like something you should be able to do...

```
function getWords(){

    var words = [];

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({detail: "words"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response) // prints ["word1, "word2" ..]
        words = response;
    });

 return words; // = []
}
```

UPDATE:
Thanks, I understand what my issue is now, but still would like some advice to solve it. 
My question is what is the best way to "ask" the background page for a list of words if I need it immediately as a parameter in another function. Can I wait for the information to come back? Should I simply call that other function from the callback? or is there some other method? 
Ideally I would like to actually implement a getWords() that doesn't return until the list comes back... Impossible? I'm open to open source libraries as well.

Comment: See [Asynchronous vs. synchronous methods](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html#sync) at the Chrome extension documentation. Tell me when you still don't understand the concept after reading that, then I'll point you to another example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `sendMessage` is an asynchronous call and you are treating it as a synchronous one. You are trying to read words before the call is actually made. There is no way to wait for it. You need to use callbacks.

```
function getWords( callback ){

    var words = [];

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({detail: "words"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response) // prints ["word1, "word2" ..]
        callback(response);
    });

}



function processWords(words){
    //do your logic in here
    console.log(words);
}
getWords(processWords);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This made me understand what was wrong but didn't really help me get to the solution I am looking for. I guess my question is what is the best way to "ask" the background page for a list of words if I need it immediately as a parameter in another function. Can I wait for the information to come back, should I simply call that other function from the callback, or is there some other method?

Comment: Unless the api has a way to force synchronous calls, I doubt you will be able to do what you want.

Comment: I will probably be getting this list pretty often. It is better to use chrome.storage or use some other method of communication?